# How to insert blank row between the rows to my query result

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, output, row

Is there a way to insert a Blank row between the rows in the "output" of a query.

I have a table with columns firstName, lastName and mobile.

My query output needs to have a blank row inserted after rows where column (mobile) having same mobile number. It makes it easier to read. Can I do this directly in the query.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT firstName, lastName, mobile
FROM table 
WHERE mobile IN (SELECT mobile FROM table GROUP BY mobile HAVING COUNT(mobile) > 1)
ORDER BY mobile DESC
```

Thanks.

Comment: Formatting of results is best left to the client application/reporting tool, however add clarity to your question with some sample data and the expected results.

Comment: Some may transfer the results of their queries to Excel or do other things that have done the same request. @Stu

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet:

```
select firstName, lastName, mobile 
from (

    SELECT firstName, lastName, mobile, mobile as sortVal 
        FROM Sheet1 
        WHERE 
              mobile IN (SELECT mobile FROM Sheet1 GROUP BY mobile HAVING COUNT(mobile) > 1)

     union all

    SELECT null, null, null, mobile as sortVal 
        FROM Sheet1 
        WHERE 
              mobile IN (SELECT mobile FROM Sheet1 GROUP BY mobile HAVING    COUNT(mobile) > 1)
    group by mobile
)u 
ORDER BY sortVal,mobile DESC
```

Output:

```
firstName   lastName    mobile
a           aa          123
b           bb          123
NULL        NULL        NULL
c           cc          14
d           dd          14
NULL        NULL        NULL
```